# Triangular matrix with a $0$ on main diagonal

Tags: matrices

I am asking if a $2 \times 2$ matrix can have $0$ as an entry on the main diagonal and still be classified as a triangular matrix.

For example, can this $2\times 2$ matrix be considered upper triangular? First row is $(0,5)$ and second row is $(0,5)$ as well.

Thank you.

Comment: The matrix $$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 5 \\ 0 & 5\end{pmatrix} $$ is upper triangular, but not *strictly* upper-triangular, since the diagonal is different from zero.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a matrix is *upper triangular* if the entries that are below the diagonal are zero. Similarly, a *lower triangular* matrix is a matrix where the entries above the diagonal are zero.

These definitions do not place a restriction on the values of the diagonal entries. For example,

$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&a\\0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$
is an upper triangular matrix.

As a side note, if you were curious, not all triangular matrices are invertible. Clearly this is true for any triangular matrix with $0$ as an element of the diagonal since the determinant will be equal to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

A square matrix is said to be upper triangular if and only if all of its entries strictly below the main diagonal are equal to $0$. Lower triangular matrices are defined similarly (replace "below" with "above").

---

For any $2 \times 2$ matrix, the only entry below the main diagonal is the bottom left entry. Therefore, any $2 \times 2$ matrix is upper triangular precisely when its bottom left entry is $0$.

In this case, we are wondering if the matrix $$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 5 \\ 0 & 5\end{pmatrix} $$ is upper triangular. Since the bottom left entry equal to $0$, this matrix is upper triangular.

An example of a $2 \times 2$ matrix that is not upper triangular is $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$ since in this case the bottom left entry is nonzero.

---

To address the first part of your question, there are square matrices whose diagonals consist of nothing but zeros, that are upper triangular. For example $$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\
                                                                     0 & 0 & 1 \\
                                                                     0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$ is upper triangular, simply because all of the entries below the main diagonal are zero. An upper triangular matrix whose diagonal consists of nothing but zeros is called strictly upper triangular. The above matrix is an example of a strictly upper triangular matrix. Similarly, any lower triangular matrix with zero diagonal is called strictly lower triangular.

More extremely, for all integers $n \geq 2$, the $n \times n$ matrix whose every entry is zero is simultaneously upper triangular, strictly upper triangular, lower triangular, and strictly lower triangular (all of the entries are zero in this case, so all four of these definitions are satisfied).